# Организация структуры проекта с несколькими модулями Golang

Tags: golang, структуры, проектирование, проект

В 1 проекте будут содержаться 3 различные программы: Repeater, Controller и Executor, полагаю что необходимо под каждый выделить свой модуль. И я хочу сделать 1 модуль который они будут импортировать с некоторым набором общих для них функций. Пока что максиум что вышло в каждый модуль добавить копии файла с этими общими функциями, что выглядит не очень. Я часа 4 ковырялся в статьях и видео уроках но так и не смог из 1 несчастного модуля импортировать функции в другой неменее несчастный модуль. Прошу помощи как можно подробнее обьясните как сделать то что я хочу если это вообще возможно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Способов как минимум три:

- гитхаб,
- инструкция `replace` в `go.mod`
- воркспейсы

ИМХО, для разработки сложного проекта из нескольких приложений и библиотек лучше всего сделать воркспейс.

## Github

Разместите библиотеку общего кода в гитхабе: `https://github.com/videxerion/common`,

в приложениях импортируйте общий код как `import "github.com/videxerion/common"`

Го автоматически найдёт и скачает модуль библиотеки.

Основное неудобство - после каждого изменения нужно пушить код в гитхаб, делать релиз, ждать, пока обновится кэш в goproxy.

Если вы в будущем планируете превратить ваш общий код в библиотеку для сторонних разработчиков, то гитхаб - самый правильный путь. Но на время разработки нужно, чтобы Го находил локальную копию библиотеки.

## go.mod replace

для разработки без гитхаба. Ваши модули во время разработки находятся в файловой системе.

Имя модуля может быть таким же (`github.com/videxerion/common`), но лежать он будет не в гитхабе, а на диске в каталоге `/path/to/common`

импорт будут выглядеть так же:

```
import "github.com/videxerion/common"
```

Как го будет находить этот модуль, если его нет в гитхабе? Для этого добавьте во `go.mod` для Repeater, Controller и Executor такие строки:

```
require github.com/videxerion/common v0.0.0

replace github.com/videxerion/common => /path/to/common
```

Тогда при сборке приложений го будут искать модуль `github.com/videxerion/common` в каталоге `/path/to/common`.

## Workspace

Воркспейсы в Go позволяют находить модули без переписывания `go.mod`.

Предполжим, вы разложили ваши проекты по каталогам:

```
workspace/Executor
workspace/Controller
workspace/common
workspace/Repeater
```

В каталоге `workspace` выполните команду:

```
go work init
```

Затем добавьте все ваши проекты в созданный воркспейс:

```
go work use ./Executor
go work use ./Controller
go work use ./common
go work use ./Repeater
```

В каталоге `workspace` обнаружится файл `go.work` с таким содержимым:

```
go 1.21.3

use (
    ./Controller
    ./Executor
    ./Repeater
    ./common
)
```

Магия воркспейса в том, что пакеты сначала ищутся в модулях воркспейса, и только затем в GOPATH и агрегаторе пакетов `proxy.golang.org`

То есть ваш модуль может называться `github.com/videxerion/common`, в `go.mod` приложений нет никаких `replace`, но благодаря воркспейсу код будет браться из `./workspace/common`.

Запускать можно как из каталога воркспейса `go run ./Controller` так и внутри каталога `Controller` `go run .`

Воркспейс даже можно сохранить в гит, сделав каталоги с кодом [гит-модулями](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)